# Performance of closing over constant value

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, if I have a loop, and inside of it I make a new function that uses the loop variable. That function keeps a reference to the loop variable because the value might change after the function is created.

Now, say my loop iterates over some strings and my function closes over the CURRENT string using a wrapper function. Would look something like this

```
for (var key in someObj) {
    (function (key) {
        someFuncList.push(function () {
            console.log(someObj[key]);
        });
    )(key)
}
```

Each of those functions have a separate key that can't change because it doesn't exist out of the function. Will the compiler optimize this so it doesn't do dynamic access? Does it even matter (performance wise)? Is the a way to "bake" a function with some constants?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by "dynamic access"? Also, there are no "constants" in JavaScript. Can you clarify your question(s)?

Comment: Well, I would imagine that `obj.prop` is somehow optimized by the compiler so that it doesn't have to calculate the hash of the string `"prop"` every time and then look it up in the table to find the actual property. However, when you do `obj["prop"]` depending on how smart the compiler is, it might or might not do the optimization. Now, my question is about the next step. Assuming it does optimize this case, can it tell that a variable isn't going to change and bake `var str = "prop"; obj[str]` into `str.prop`.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work the way you're asking. The runtime looks up the property every time because objects are mutable. To illustrate from your example, it appears that some other code will iterate over `someFuncList` at some future time, right? Well, in theory, the object `someObj` could be modified in such a way that one or more of the keys is removed, new keys are added, and maybe the removed key is re-appended. Crazy example, but legal in JavaScript. The object can never be "baked" because it is mutable.

Comment: This benchmark doesn't really agree with you http://jsperf.com/dynamic-access. It seems that the compiler might do some more analysis.

Comment: I didn't say the performance would be identical. I answered your questions about "constants" and dynamic access and whether the object's property list can change. A JavaScript runtime environment (not a compiler, by the way) may exhibit different performance characteristics for each type of property access syntax. There's no guarantee that each environment (GC, FF, IE, Node, Rhino, etc.) will have the same performance characteristics, nor that a particular access method will perform best in every environment.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific. I know that JavaScript as a language doesn't define stuff like this. What I actually wanted to know is how it performs on modern compilers and if optimizations like these are something to expect. I use the word compiler because I assume that's what they usually do with JavaScript code. I know V8 does.

Comment: The kind of optimization you're looking for -- "baking" -- cannot be implemented because objects are mutable. The property list is not constant. The offsets are not guaranteed to exist in the future. In your example code, try this experiment: run the code to push the functions into someFuncList, then remove one of the keys from someObj, then iterate over someFuncList and invoke the functions. When you get to the key that was removed, the call to `console.log(someObj[key])` will print `undefined`. The key existed when the function was created, but it doesn't exist when the function is called.